# sorting list of list containing datetime.date in increasing/decreasing order to create pretty table/csv file

Tags: python, sorting, csv, prettytable

I have a list of lists containing `datetime` object.

```
table_of_list= [[name, email, address, details, date_last_contacted], 
 [u'Jane Doe', u'jdoe@abc.com', u'sillybilly', u'dodo', datetime.date(2016, 11, 1)]
 [u'John Doe', u'jedoe@abc.com', u'123 house',u'random', dateTime.date(2016,10,1)]
 [].....
]
```

I am populating this list of lists, so that I can utilize this to do two things:

- create a pretty table using `prettyTable` module
- use this to create a `.csv` file

**Problem:**

I need to organize the way the rows are being displayed sorted by the `date_last_contacted` order in both pretty table and `csv`. 
Pretty table sort is not working for me maybe because I have a header. But not entirely sure.
I am new to python, not sure how the lambda thing works, but can i some how sort the list of lists before utilizing it to create `.csv` file or pretty table.

In short, How can I sort the lists within the `table_of_list` in the most pythonic way?

Comment: `list.sort(key=...)` or `list = sorted(list, key=...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sorted` function where you set `key` to a `lambda` function that returns the last element - to sort by the last element.

We take the first row of the original table as a header and then add the rest of the rows, which are sorted.

```
sorted_table = [table_of_list[0]]
sorted_table.extend(sorted(table_of_list[1:], key=lambda row: row[-1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list = sorted(list, key=...)` or `list.sort(key=...)`.

First method lets you use slicing to get/set only part of list - without changing first row.

```
import datetime

table_of_list = [['name', 'email', 'address', 'details', 'date_last_contacted'], 
 [u'Jane Doe', u'jdoe@abc.com', u'sillybilly', u'dodo', datetime.date(2016,11,1) ],
 [u'John Doe', u'jedoe@abc.com', u'123 house',u'random', datetime.date(2016,10,1) ]
]

table_of_list[1:] = sorted(table_of_list[1:], key=lambda x: x[4])

print(table_of_list)
```